# Could not locate apply /clojure/core/vector__init.class or apply/clojure/core/vector.clj on classpath

Tags: java, clojure, filenotfoundexception

I am getting the following error when I try to run my program: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate apply
/clojure/core/vector__init.class or apply/clojure/core/vector.clj on classpath:
, compiling:(erbium/compile.clj:1:1)`. It seems to be pointing to file below and suggests that I need to put `clojure.core/vector` in my dependencies. Is it not included by default?

```
(ns erbium.compile
    (require `[clojure.string :as string])
)

(defn produce-out "Convert 'command %1 %2 %3' with stack [5 6 7] to 'command 5 6 7'" [word stack definitions]
    (let [
            code (definitions word) ; dictionary/hash lookup. eg. "println" -> "echo $1"
            replacement (fn [match] (-> match second Long/parseLong dec stack str))
         ]
        ; evaluate arguments. eg. "echo %1"
        ;                         stack=["blah"]
        ;                         -> "echo blah"
        (string/replace code #"%(\d)" replacement)
    )
)

(defn parse-word "Verifies that word is in defintitions and then returns (produce-out word stack)" [word stack definitions]
    (if (some #{word} (keys definitions))
        (produce-out word stack)
    )
)

(defn compile "Main compile function" [code]
    (let [
            split-code (string/split code #"\s")
            definitions {
                "println" "echo %1"
                "+" "%1 + %2"
                "-" "%1 - %2"
            }
            stack []
        ]

        (for [word [split-code]]
            (if (integer? (read-string word))
                (do
                    (println "Found integer" word)
                    (def stack (conj stack (read-string word)))
                    (println "Adding to argument stack:" stack)
                )

                ; else
                (do
                    (parse-word word stack definitions)
                    (def stack [])
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This file is loaded by the core file via `(load "compile")` if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the answer, the "require" appears in the namespace declaration "ns". `ns` is actually a macro that expands to a series of statements to create the namespace, and do some setup.

This macro treats statements like `(:require ...)` as calls to a function with the name `require`, and automatically quotes any following arguments. Since you had specified a quote yourself:

```
(ns erbium.compile
  (require '[clojure.string :as string]))
```

Then the result ends up being double-quoted, and the call to `require` ends up being:

```
... (require (quote (quote [clojure.string :as string])))
```

So it ends up trying to load a namespace called "quote" followed by a vector that was syntactically in the wrong place. :)

The `ns` macro is a standard and convenient way to set up namespaces, but it took me a long time to learn it properly. I found the best way was to copy other people's setup code until I learnt how to do it right.

Incidentally, the use of `require` instead of `:require` does not matter, though the standard is to use `:require` so it does not look like a direct call to that function.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. So the error message was correct just not particularly useful unless you know what to look for ;)

Answer (score 2):

the first error I see is this:

```
(require `[clojure.string :as string])
```

It should be like this:

```
(:require [clojure.string :as string])
```

in a regular clojure source file. This fixed it for me.

That said, here comes some general advices:

1. There are a lot of formatting "mistakes". Of course you can format your code as you would like to, however, it's easier for others to follow if you stick to basic formatting principles. Here is a nice collection of them: https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide Most editors implement some formatting tool.
2. `split-code (str/split code #"\s")` this won't work as you required `[clojure.string :as string]` So change it to: `split-code (string/split code #"\s")`
3. I am not sure about (load ...) and in which context one uses that generally. However, for starting to learn clojure I recommend Lighttable as it has instant feedback built in which is very valuable when learning something new.

Comment: Well that was easy, thank you. The error message doesn't seem to even mention clojure.string though

Comment: Admittedly, error message can be hard to read / interpret, for me they took more time to learn than "clojure" itself ;-)